# AWS RDS Service creation: Unable to select subnet for RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create AWS RDS Service and I am using the default VPC, and like many would know - it has three subnets associated with it. But during the creation of RDS, I am not able to pick the subnets (i want to choose a subnet so I can control the AZ and CIDR of the RDS). Below is the screenshot. Could some one point, how i can get the subnets option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Subnets for RDS are defined in a [subnet group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Subnets), rather than you selecting the subnet itself during creation.

The subnet group will contain multiple subnets that an RDS instance could be launched in, when you create RDS instances with either Multi-AZ or Read only replicas this same subnet group will be used.

You can create a new subnet group in the console, via IaC ([CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbsubnet-group.html) or [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_subnet_group)) or via the [CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/create-db-subnet-group.html). However, this will need to be done before you create the RDS instance.